# How to calculate inside React states?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, html-table, react-hooks

I am currently making a loan calculator app with React and I want to calculate monthly interest depending on the left amount to pay back.

The Interest column is displaying each month the interest from the total principal remaining at the end of that month, depending on the interest rate. For example, if the user selects the loan amount of £10,000 with a duration of 4 months and an interest rate of 3%.

The Principal column is displaying the total requested loan amount divided equally over the number of selected months (in this case, £10,000 / 4 = £2,500).

1st month: £10000 * 3% = £300

2nd month: £7500 (£10000 - £2500 repaid on Month 1) * 3% = £225

3rd month: £5000 * 3% = £150

4th month: £2500 * 3% = £75

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  const [loan, setLoan] = useState(10000);
  const [duration, setDuration] = useState(1);
  const [interest, setInterest] = useState(0);
  const [dates, setDates] = useState([]);

  const getInterest = () => {
    let amountRepaid = loan - getPrincipal();
    let interestedAmount = (amountRepaid * interest) / 100;
    return Math.round((interestedAmount + Number.EPSILON) * 100) / 100;
  };

  const getPrincipal = () => {
    let dividedAmount = loan / duration;
    return Math.round((dividedAmount + Number.EPSILON) * 100) / 100;
  };

  const getTotalRepayment = () => {
    return Math.round((getInterest() + getPrincipal() + Number.EPSILON) * 100) / 100;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    let datesArray = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < duration; i++) {
      let date = new Date();
      date = new Date(date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 1 + i));
      datesArray.push(date.getDate() + "/" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + date.getFullYear());
    }

    setDates(datesArray);
  }, [duration]);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <header>
        <h1>Your Loan</h1>
      </header>
      <main>
        <form>
          <div className="row g-3 align-items-center">
            <div className="col-auto">
              <label htmlFor="loan-input" className="form-label">
                Loan Amount (£)
              </label>
            </div>
            <div className="col-auto">
              <input
                type="text"
                className="form-control"
                id="loan-input"
                value={loan}
                onChange={e => setLoan(e.target.value)}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="row g-3 align-items-center">
            <div className="col-auto">
              <label htmlFor="duration-input" className="form-label">
                Duration (in Months)
              </label>
            </div>
            <div className="col-auto">
              <input
                type="text"
                className="form-control"
                id="duration-input"
                value={duration}
                onChange={e => setDuration(e.target.value)}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
        <div className="row g-3 align-items-center">
          <div className="col-auto">
            <label htmlFor="interest-range" className="form-label">
              Interest Rate (%) : {interest}
            </label>
          </div>
          <div className="col-auto">
            <input
              type="range"
              value={interest}
              onChange={e => setInterest(e.target.value)}
              min="0"
              max="10"
              step="1"
              className="form-range"
              id="interest-range"
            />
          </div>
          <table className="table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">Repayment Date</th>
                <th scope="col">Principal</th>
                <th scope="col">Interest</th>
                <th scope="col">Total Repayment</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {dates.map((date, index) => (
                <tr key={index}>
                  <td>{date}</td>
                  <td>{getPrincipal()}</td>
                  <td>{getInterest()}</td>
                  <td>{getTotalRepayment()}</td>
                </tr>
              ))}
              <tr>
                <td>Total</td>
                <td>{loan}</td>
                <td></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </main>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I can't seem to get the loan remaining on each calculation.

Answer (score 0):

> **This might Help you**.
> [here is the snippest](https://ilhfq.csb.app/)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [loan, setLoan] = useState(10000);
  const [duration, setDuration] = useState(1);
  const [interest, setInterest] = useState(0);
  const [dates, setDates] = useState([]);

  const getInterest = (month) => {
    let amountRepaid = loan - getPrincipal(month);
    let interestedAmount = (amountRepaid * interest) / 100;
    return Math.round((interestedAmount + Number.EPSILON) * 100) / 100;
  };

  const getPrincipal = (month) => {
    let dividedAmount = (loan / duration)*month;
    return Math.round((dividedAmount + Number.EPSILON) * 100) / 100;
  };

  const getTotalRepayment = (month) => {
    return (
      Math.round((getInterest(month) + getPrincipal(month) + Number.EPSILON) * 100) / 100
    );
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    let datesArray = [];

    for (let i = 1; i <= duration; i++) {
      let date = new Date();
      date = new Date(date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 1 + i));
      datesArray.push({
        date: `${date.getDate()}/${date.getMonth() + 1}/${date.getFullYear()}`,
        month: i
      });
    }

    setDates(datesArray);
  }, [duration]);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <header>
        <h1>Your Loan</h1>
      </header>
      <main>
        <form>
          <div className="row g-3 align-items-center">
            <div className="col-auto">
              <label htmlFor="loan-input" className="form-label">
                Loan Amount (£)
              </label>
            </div>
            <div className="col-auto">
              <input
                type="text"
                className="form-control"
                id="loan-input"
                value={loan}
                onChange={(e) => setLoan(e.target.value)}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="row g-3 align-items-center">
            <div className="col-auto">
              <label htmlFor="duration-input" className="form-label">
                Duration (in Months)
              </label>
            </div>
            <div className="col-auto">
              <input
                type="text"
                className="form-control"
                id="duration-input"
                value={duration}
                onChange={(e) => setDuration(e.target.value)}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
        <div className="row g-3 align-items-center">
          <div className="col-auto">
            <label htmlFor="interest-range" className="form-label">
              Interest Rate (%) : {interest}
            </label>
          </div>
          <div className="col-auto">
            <input
              type="range"
              value={interest}
              onChange={(e) => setInterest(e.target.value)}
              min="0"
              max="10"
              step="1"
              className="form-range"
              id="interest-range"
            />
          </div>
          <table className="table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">Repayment Date</th>
                <th scope="col">Principal</th>
                <th scope="col">Interest</th>
                <th scope="col">Total Repayment</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {dates.map((emi, index) => {
                const { date, month } = emi; 
                return (
                  <tr key={index}>
                    <td>{date}</td>
                    <td>{getPrincipal(month)}</td>
                    <td>{getInterest(month)}</td>
                    <td>{getTotalRepayment(month)}</td>
                  </tr>
                );
              })}
              <tr>
                <td>Total</td>
                <td>{loan}</td>
                <td></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </main>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```